# Why RTP doesn't support multiple streams to one port but RTSP does?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp, rtp

I use `ffmpeg` for streaming a video using RTP protocol.
Why I can't send multiple streams to one RTP port, but RTSP that uses RTP can?
I started a RTSP server that listens 8554 TCP port and 8000/8001 RTP/RTCP. It easily can receive both video and audio streams to one port 8000, I've checked it with wireshark. But when I try to do the same with pure RTP using ffmpeg, it prints me an error

```
Only one stream supported in the RTP muxer
```

And if I want to stream a video with sound, I have to split them into two streams and send to different RTP ports. Or maybe I can somehow make it receive multiple streams to one port via RTP?

Could you explain me, why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

The RFC for RTP explains a bit [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-5.2)

> For example, in a teleconference
> composed of audio and video media encoded separately, each medium
> SHOULD be carried in a separate RTP session with its own destination
> transport address.

> Separate audio and video streams SHOULD NOT be carried in a single
> RTP session and demultiplexed based on the payload type or SSRC
> fields.  Interleaving packets with different RTP media types but
> using the same SSRC would introduce several problems

Also see the multiplex guidelines draft [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-avtcore-multiplex-guidelines-08.html#rfc.section.3.2.1). So it is possible to multiplex RTP streams but the software you are using may not support it.

I can't answer how RTSP handles this however. The answer is likely in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326.html#section-1.1)